# HTML Scraping with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, ajax, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Can some one tell me the best way to get the contents using HTMLAgilityPack that i mention below from the html.

In the HTML provided i need to scrape `value` of the ID "img" and set the values for `x` and `y` for them to be used in another function.

The relevant HTML is

```
<div id="values">
<input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" value='0' />
<input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" value='0' />
<input type="hidden" id="img" name="img" value="86932" />
<input type="hidden" id="source" name = "source" value="center" />
```

These values are being sent to the function in the javascript displayed below

```
submitClick(document.getElementById("img").getAttribute("value"), 
              document.getElementById("x").getAttribute("value"), 
              document.getElementById("y").getAttribute("value"), 
              'tiled'  );
```

Can some body help me out by telling how i should proceed ...

I have written the following code that gets me the html data for the page

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.Method = "GET";
using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentNode;
```

Now that i have got the root how should i search for the parameters and then send them by GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up where you left off in your sample code above you could just grab the values like this

```
string imgValue = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@id = \"img\"]").GetAttributeValue("value", "0");
string xValue = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@id = \"x\"]").GetAttributeValue("value", "0");
string yValue = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@id = \"y\"]").GetAttributeValue("value", "0");
```

Where the first example above is basically saying find the first node of type "input" that has the "id" attribute that equals "img" and get me the value of it's "value" attribute.

And then just append to the dest URL and send the Get Request as you did to get the initial HTML.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot ... but could you tell me one more thing ... I have an element like this <div id="image_src" style="display: block; ">
      <img id="captcha_img" src="" alt="image" onclick="imageClick(event)" style="cursor:crosshair;">
     </div>  In this how can i detect the src ?

Comment: I added a little explanation to the answer that may help. but specifically you could get the value of the "src" attribute like this string imgValue = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@id = \"captcha_img\"]").GetAttributeValue("src", "0");

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the Html Agility Pack for this because I don't know how to make it feed back to the originating website. Instead, I'd use [WatiN](http://watin.org/). WatiN is built for driving a browser for testing purposes, but I've found it extremely useful when I have to scrape websites that are outside my control (such as Facebook or Wal-Mart). Downside is that it *is* driving an actual browser window so it's not something you hide from a user. Upside is that you can easily simulate mouse clicks and form field text entries.